# Is there an R function for removing parts of row names?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a column "SampleID" containing a series of sample IDs, all of which end with "_Dup". I want to remove the "_Dup" suffix from all row names in the column.

Here's an example of the df:

```
df
SampleID      Concentration
sample1_Dup   1
sample2_Dup   2
sample3_Dup   3
```

The result I'm looking for is this:

```
df
SampleID      Concentration
sample 1      1
sample 2      2
sample 3      3
```

I've searched for solutions to this problem using base R and the tidyverse but haven't been able to find anything on modifying all row names in a column.

Comment: If you just want to remove "Dup" suffix you could do `df$SampleID <- sub("_Dup$", "", df$SampleID)`

Answer (score 2):

Try using `sub`:

```
df$SampleID <- sub("(\\d+)_[^_]+$", " \\1", df$SampleID)
df$SampleID

[1] "sample 1" "sample 2" "sample 3"
```

The strategy here is to match *and* capture the sample number, followed by the final underscore and the rest of the sample ID.  Then, we replace with just a space followed by that captured sample number.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would just creat a new variable like this.

```
df$new_var<-substr(df$SampleID, 1,7)
```

that should take the first 7 characters of the string and put it in a new column.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the column into 2, and then remove the unwanted column.

```
separate(data, col, into, sep = "[^[:alnum:]]+", remove = TRUE,
  convert = FALSE, extra = "warn", fill = "warn", ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

A tidyverse-style solution:

```
df %>%
    mutate(SampleID = SampleID %>% str_replace('(.*)([0-9])_Dup$', '\\1 \\2'))
```

The tidyverse-style string manipulation fuctions are from `stringr`, and all begin with names like `str_XYZ`.  They are capable of using regular expressions.  Here, we used "named groups" -- that's the part of the regular expression inside the parenthesis.  The first named group `(*.)` is everything that comes before any single number.  A single number is the second named group (`([0-9])`).  We put the two parts together with a space between them in the 3rd argument to `str_replace`, which is `\\1 \\2`.